# Why is there a space on top of unordered list items?

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-lists

**PROBLEM:** There is a space on top of unordered list items. This space appears in Firefox 18.0.1

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    list-style: square;
    margin-left: 20px
}
```

**WORKING DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vpdd7/

Comment: which browser, I don't see any space in Chrome.

Comment: When using jsFiddle to show a css problem, be sure to uncheck the *Normalized CSS* option (left panel).

Comment: @Bulat I see his problem using FF19.

Comment: Inspect your actual styles in Firebug; there are default styles applied by Firefox itself, which you might need to address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with list styles clashing with inline elements preceding/containing block elements such as `h3` and `p`. This issue does not occur if you

- [set `ul` to `list-style-type: none`](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vpdd7/7)
- [set `li` to anything other than `display: list-item`](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vpdd7/3)
- [set `a` to `display: block`](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vpdd7/4)
- [remove the `a` element altogether](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vpdd7/5)
- [set `h3` to anything other than `display: block`](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vpdd7/6)

I can't find anything in the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#list-style) that would determine whether this behavior is a bug in Firefox, or a bug in other browsers. In fact, under [`list-style-position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style-position), it says that the exact position or layout of the marker box (containing the bullet) is undefined, even with respect to the box that's created by the `li` element itself (the principal box) or any of its children.

Given your situation, the third option may be the best workaround that wouldn't compromise the layout much, if at all. If you're going to turn the entire contents of the list item into a link anyway, you may as well display it as a block. That way everything is safely contained in a block box, whose rendering is very clearly-defined and completely reliable.

Answer (score -1):

h3 elements display as block elements. This means they take up the whole width of the browser window, with a space above and below them. You need to change your h3 tags to display as inline elements so they don't break the flow of the document. You can change a block element to an inline element like this:

CSS:

```
  h3{
      display:inline;
  }
```

Here's the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpdd7/2/)

Comment: Block elements are not affected by whitespace, and should not be.

Comment: Not whitespace, but they will always appear on a new line if a block or inline element is placed before or after them.